# What is the difference between define and require in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

What is the difference between `define` and `require`, and when should I use each of them? I have read different answers on Stack Overflow, but I still haven't been able to understand.

For example, if this was on `main.js` (config file require points to), what is the difference?

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
 do something with $            
});

require(["jquery"], function($) {
 do something with $            
});
```

Is `$/jQ` guaranteed to be loaded and ready in both?

Answer (score 3):

They do the same thing internally. But...... you should define your entry point of your app using `require` and define the rest of the modules using `define`. I find that this keeps it clear what role the current module you're looking at is actually playing in terms of your whole app.